# Configure Swipe between full screen apps

Tags: macbook-pro, mouse, trackpad

Im using my macbookpro with external everything, computer is closed. Im missing the trackpad tho.. Is there a way to configure the trackpad option 'swipe between full screen apps'on my mouse?

Im using a Corsair Harpoon mouse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your mouse has it's own drivers, much like Razer Synapse, you can assign <kbd>^ control</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>^ control</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>, the shortcuts for moving left and right a space, respectively, to certain mouse buttons.

This cannot be done natively in macOS Mouse System Preferences. A third-party app/driver is required to do this.